# Panel clear everything

Tags: c#, controls, panel

I would like to reset a panel to its initial state. For example, I set an image as background, and I draw graphics on a part of the panel. I have to clear everything. How?

Comment: can you just abandon the old one and create assign `new Panle();` to the reference?

Comment: I suppose you are using the designer at compile time and that you want to "clear" the panel at runtime ? What other changes do you need to clear, more details would be nice.

Comment: @Vincent B: I just need to clear the panel. I wrote a property "ClearPanel", inside it I tried \n 1. set the background = null \n 2. panel.Controls.Clear() ; but nothing works.

Comment: Rauf K: A property or a method ? Have you thought of calling suspendLayout() and resumeLayout(true) for the modification, are you sure your method is called ?

Comment: Even panel.controls.clear() does not work means this is strange then

Comment: None of the proposed solution worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Resetting a Windows Forms form's elements to an initialized state (C#/.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337649/resetting-a-windows-forms-forms-elements-to-an-initialized-state-c-net)*

Answer (score 22):

You have to clear the panel first:

```
panel1.Controls.Clear();
```

Then call the initial form:

```
panel1.Controls.Add(orig_form);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code to delete all graphics from the panel

```
panel1.Invalidate();
```

If there is something you need to add to panel's initial state then after you call invalidate you again have to set those things.

If the initial state of panels needs some graphics or data you can put that in panel's graphics event, so everytime invalidate is called your panel get the initial state with those items.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `panel1.refresh();` command.  It resets the panel to its initial state.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only solution that worked for me:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Clear button
{
    using (g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent); // You can choose another color
                                    // for your background here.
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//clear Data
{
   panel1.Controls.Clear();            
   this.Refresh();
}
```